# Is there an advanced way to label in ArcMap so that the label will not be dropped?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, labeling, cartography

Is there an advanced way to label in ArcMap so that the label will not be dropped?

Answer (score 6):

On the labels tab of the layer properties, click Placement Properties...
On the conflict detection tab, turn on the checkbox for "Place overlapping labels".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Kevin's answer above, which may work for your purposes, I also highly recommend you take a look at the Maplex engine extension.  It's pricey (what isn't?), but if you work at an institution that has access to it, Maplex is hard to beat in terms of label placement customization.  I'm pretty sure it is included with the ArcInfo license.

http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/maplex/index.html

Comment: Even then you will run into the same problem at times, but there are similar options such as 'background label (placed first)' and 'never remove (allow overlap)'.

Comment: It is included with ArcInfo.

Comment: I think it's included in all license levels now. I have it in ArcBasic.