# extract labeled feature in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

We use Arcmap to label our features(points), now since there are too many features, so some of them are labeled while some not, now I wonder if we can extract the features labeled?

Comment: What sort of annotation? Map annotation, geodatabase or feature linked?

Comment: I am sorry, I am exactly sure your meaning. While we use the geodatabase(.gdb) as the data source, and then use the `Label Features`.

Comment: Related (duplicate of?): http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94446/is-it-possible-to-remove-features-whose-labels-are-not-displayed/94492#comment132040_94492 Asker there wanted to not display features not labeled, this question is asking to extract the ones that are. The solution given at the other question does that (maybe). At any rate, you should read the info given in the other question.

Comment: Oh, you're talking about labels and not annotations! Labels are volatile and change each time the map is refreshed... My apologies. I don't think there's any way to return the features not labelled from the label engine; you could implement your own feature renderer but that's way advanced ArcObjects, much easier to convert to feature linked annotation and join then definition query the empty ones out... but that makes it permanent.

Comment: Yes, in this post http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94446/is-it-possible-to-remove-features-whose-labels-are-not-displayed/94492#comment132040_94492, I try to set the label at a fix position, and convert the label to annotation, then I am not sure how to get the points according to the annotation. Find the closest feature around a given annotation?

Comment: @giser You would just do a regular join between the points class and the annotation class. The text string field in the annotation class should be the same as whatever field you're creating the label from in the points class. Once the join is complete, you can use the status field from the annotation class to sort the table and select records that have placed labels.

Answer (score 1):

If you switch to using annotation instead of dynamic labels.
But that is not my recommendation.
Take a look at this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19034/is-there-an-advanced-way-to-label-in-arcmap-so-that-the-label-will-not-be-droppe)